# How to check that ApolloError is caused by client internet connection?

Tags: javascript, exception, apollo, apollo-client, internet-connection

`ApolloError` has [networkError](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/#network-errors) prop, but it is set when server responds with 4** or 5** status code.

And how to check that the problem is caused by bad internet connection?

```
try {
   apolloClient.query(someQuery)
} catch (error) {
  if (isInternetConnectionError(error)) { // how to check this?
    Alert.alert('Please check your internet connection!')
  } else {
    logException(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that there is no good way to get that (nice work Apollo), but this is the exact error state that comes when there is no internet:

```js
export const isNetworkError = (error: unknown) => {
  return (
    error instanceof ApolloError &&
    error.message === 'Network request failed' &&
    error.graphQLErrors.length === 0 &&
    error.clientErrors.length === 0 &&
    error.networkError &&
    Object.keys(error.networkError).length === 0
  );
};
```

Relevant for `"@apollo/client": "3.4.7"`

Or here is much shorter version that should work:

```js
export const isNetworkError = (error: unknown) => {
  return (
    error instanceof ApolloError &&
    error.message === 'Network request failed'
  );
};
```